# Photowall with double sized highlight pictures

Tags: css

We are working on a picture gallery site and can't find a solution for following problem.

The picture wall contains several images. Some image (n Percent) should by highlighted and get displayed double sized on the wall.

[image: sample wall]

The issue is, that I have no idea to fill the empty space left of the large picture, because its a new line.

Any ideas.

I created a fiddle for this sample here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1s3uho6/1/)

```
    <body>
  <div class="size1">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
    <div class="size1">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
    <div class="size2">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
    <div class="size1">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
    <div class="size1">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
     <div class="size1">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
    <div class="size1">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
     <div class="size1">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
    <div class="size1">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
      <div class="size1">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
     <div class="size1">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
    <div class="size1">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
     <div class="size1">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
    <div class="size1">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
</body>

    div {
  background-color: #f00;
  float: left;
}

.size1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.size2{
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

The following browsers now natively support CSS Grid Layout.

1. Firefox v52
2. Chrome v57 for Linux, macOS, Windows, iOS, and Android
3. Safari v10.1
4. iOS Safari v10.3
5. Opera v44

---

This kind of layout requirement is what the [CSS Grid Layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/) spec aims to address. The introduction to the spec reads:

> Grid Layout is a new layout model for CSS that has powerful abilities to control the sizing and positioning of boxes and their contents. Unlike [Flexible Box Layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/), which is single-axis–oriented, Grid Layout is optimized for 2-dimensional layouts: those in which alignment of content is desired in both dimensions.

Native browser support for *CSS Grid Layout* is likely to start landing in major browsers soon *(as shown [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid))* and is currently featured behind a flag in some. For non-supporting browsers this JavaScript [polyfill](https://github.com/FremyCompany/css-grid-polyfill/blob/master/bin/css-polyfills.min.js) will be necessary.

As an example, *CSS Grid Layout* syntax is shown in the following CSS:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box box--double">5</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  ...
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS** *using the Grid layout model*

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  margin: 5px;
}

.box--double {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}
```

**DEMO**

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5g00pfj/8/) which utilizes *CSS Grid Layout* syntax (inc. the polyfill) to provide a general gist.

---

Alternatively, [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) may be able to achieve this, however long term this will always be dependent on JavaScript.

---

#### Responsive Web Design (RWD)

The [CSS Grid Layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/) module includes several features to simplify the creation of responsive designs. Two pertinent features which address the issues raised in the comments are:

**1** [Flexible Lengths](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#fr-unit)

The `fr` unit should be used instead of specifying the relative column width as a percentage. The main benefit of the `fr` unit is that it avoids having to manually recalculate the percentage when the number of columns change via a media query - *(You simply change the value for the number of columns only)*:

```css
/* Avoid using percentages like this */
.wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 14.286%);
    ...
}

/* Use the 'fr' unit instead */
.wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    ...
}
```

**2** [grid-auto-flow-dense](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#valdef-grid-auto-flow-dense)

Three values that can be assigned to the [grid-auto-flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#propdef-grid-auto-flow) property, namely `row`, `column`, and `dense`.

```css
.wrapper {
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    ...
}
```

In some situations when `row`, or `column` values are used it can produce unwanted holes/gaps in the layout. When specifying `dense` an algorithm attempts to fill those holes/gaps in, however this can sometimes change the the order of the items. This feature is very similar to the way [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) places items in a different position based on available vertical space.

**DEMO FOR RWD**

Here is a responsive [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5g00pfj/15/) that uses both the `fr` unit and the `dense` value to avoid any gaps/holes in the layout.

---

***EDIT(5): Updated list of browsers supporting CSS Grid Layout.***

***EDIT(4): Added note regarding Chrome 57 implementing CSS Grid Layout spec.***

***EDIT(3): Added note regarding Firefox 52 implementing CSS Grid Layout spec.***

***EDIT(2): Add useful CSS Grid Layout features for achieving RWD***

***EDIT(1): Changed sample code to terse version and updated link to external fiddle***

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CSS only solution, fully responsive, based on [CSS columns](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/)

```css
.columns >div {
  background-color: #f00;
  float: left;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.size1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.size2{
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.columns {
  width: 660px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-columns: 200px 3;
  -moz-columns: 200px 3;
  columns: 200px 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  column-gap: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 689px) {
  .columns {
    width: 440px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-columns: 200px 2;
    -moz-columns: 200px 2;
    columns: 200px 2;
  } 
}
@media (max-width: 459px) {
  .columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 220px;
  }
  .columns div {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
  .columns .size1 {
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 10px)
  }
  .columns .size2 {
    flex-basis: calc(100% - 10px)
  }
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 920px) { /* 4 columns */
  .columns {
    width: 880px;
    -webkit-columns: 200px 4;
    -moz-columns: 200px 4;
    columns: 200px 4;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1140px) { /* 5 columns */
  .columns {
    width: 1100px;
    -webkit-columns: 200px 5;
    -moz-columns: 200px 5;
    columns: 200px 5;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1360px) { /* 6 columns */
.columns {
    width: 1320px;
    -webkit-columns: 200px 6;
    -moz-columns: 200px 6;
    columns: 200px 6;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1580px) { 
  /* respect the principle above to add as many columns as you like */
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="size2"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size2"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size2"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size2"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
</div>
```

For mobiles media query interval, I used `flexbox`, but it's just to show it's possible. You really don't have to, you can stick to `box-model`.

**Note:** You can define further media intervals. The basic idea is to have a multiple of 220px and limit it to widths that have sufficient room for all columns.

Here's the fiddle (I added it as, for some reason, SO won't allow me to resize the snippet window under ~480px, while jsFiddle does.)
[<kbd>fiddle here</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/b044pbz6/)

---

This solution assumes you will always pair 2 small items together (so they occupy 1 row). If you want a solution where this condition doesn't have to be met by whoever adds content, and automatically tries to pair small items when they are `single`, you need `javascript`.

---

**Timeline solution** (based on comments info)

I'm guessing this is what you need? (If you decide to change classnames, you'll need to adjust both `js` and `CSS`).

```js
$('.timeline .size2').each(function(){
  //moving required number of small'uns so they fill the column
  var prevIndex = $(this).prevAll('.size2,.wrap').eq(0).index(), 
      diff = $(this).index() - (prevIndex + 1), 
      toMove = (3 - (diff  % 3)) %3;
  if (toMove) {
    for (var i = 1; i < toMove + 1; i++) {
      $(this).nextAll('.size1').eq(0).addClass('moved').insertBefore($(this))
    }
  }
  var wrap = $('<div />', {
    class:'wrap'
  })

  //wrap 2 small'uns to make a row under a big'un
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    wrap.append($(this).nextAll('.size1').eq(0));
  }
  wrap.insertAfter($(this));
})
```

```css
.timeline [class^="size"] {
  background-color: red;
}

.size1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.size2{
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.timeline {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 330px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.timeline .wrap {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size2"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size2"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size2"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size2"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
  <div class="size1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach. Unfortunatly I need a line based approach because I need the time based order.

Comment: What you need is achievable with `display:flex; flex-direction: column; height: {/* size in px for 3 small boxes */}`. I can't do this now, I'll get back on it in ~8 hours and provide an example if you still need it (you don't get another answer). And... hey! One more thing: ***not giving full information on requirements***, especially when it's a bit more complex, it's really not cool. You should try to minimize the effort on whoever is willing to help's part.

Comment: Hey Andrei, sorry for the additional effort. The I got the sorting problem first after reading your approach. Sorry for this. Thanks for your involvement! I'll try my best next time.

Comment: Updated with what you seem to need, using `jQuery` and `flexbox`. If you're not using `jQuery`, it should be done in `vanilla`, but for me it was faster like this. Also please note you should run the `CSS` through [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) before deploying. The script adjusts and moves elements no matter how you place them (making sure all gaps are filled).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to shorten the fiddle from RobC and replaced the fixed width in pixels with relative width in percent. So it is a little more responsive. But still have some gaps which you may prevent with some rules, like "no 2 big boxes side by side" and so on.

The Html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" /> 
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" /> 
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/f33/fff" class="box--double" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/f33/fff" class="box--double" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/f33/fff" class="box--double" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/f33/fff" class="box--double" />  
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/f33/fff" class="box--double" />  
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333/fff" class="" />
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 16.666%);
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 20%);
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33.333%);
  }
}

.wrapper > img {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border: solid 1px white;
}
.box::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.box--double {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
    grid-row: auto / span 2;
}
```

[The fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq5b203u/3/)

Comment: Thanks for playing around with this. I've played a little bit with your fiddle and think, I can fix the gaps with some rules on the source data. I've figured out, that the following rules will avoid gaps as much as possible:

- show only columns with factor three (3, 6 or 9 columns)
- no highlight picture in the first three pics
- avoid highlight pics dividable through three
- minimum four pics between two highlight pics