# Photo gallery with with equal height for each image in the same line

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox, grid, jquery-masonry

I want to make a photo gallery where the images have all (or almost) different sizes.

The idea is therefore to create a grid whose image widths would be potentially different but that for each line the image height present on it the height is identical.

Here is a schematic view of what I would like to get:
[image]

Here is my basic HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x325">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x311">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x313">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/420x301">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x675">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x401">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x921">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x300">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x303">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x562">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1330x586">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x325">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x311">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x313">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x301">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x675">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x401">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x921">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x300">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x303">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x562">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1330x586">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/169x234">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/169x234">
</div>
```

I tried the plugin jquery masonry but the result was not conclusive.

I also tried a solution via css Flexbox, with this CSS:

```
.container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .item {
        padding: 10px;
        min-width: 150px;
        max-height: 420px;
        max-width: 75%;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .item img {
        object-fit: cover;
        height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
```

The height of the images of the same line is identical but I have big margins that appear in some places that I would not want to have:
example here : https://jsfiddle.net/sadlig/dc6785yx/

Maybe there is a simpler way to do that? or a JS library may exist to do that?

Comment: Do you just want a pre-decided set of sizes that images could be put into and cropped/fit to those preset sizes? Or do you want something that will "decide" what height each row should be, what images should go in what rows, etc to make an arrangement dynamically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Photowall with double sized highlight pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114205/photowall-with-double-sized-highlight-pictures)

Comment: Did you fin a solution? I am trying to do the same thing but I don't know where to strat.

Comment: @JonathanAurry sorry, just see your comment. I don't find a simple solution to do this. Pure CSS solutions were not suitable, masonry plugins did not meet expectations at all. So I had to code a javascript function to do the Job.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add flex: 1 to the child item and this should make all of the items the same height.

Two other possible solutions would be to use a Match Height JS plugin and you can write something like. http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

```
$('.item').matchHeight({
  byRow: true,
  property: 'height'
});
```

If you're looking for the latest and greatest then you could also check out CSS Grid but might not be supported in all browsers.